# Arquitetura MVC de Rotas e Controllers com várias versões usando Spark

Tags: java, mvc, spark

Estou implementando uma API Rest em Java utilizando o framework [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/). Preciso dividir as rotas em duas versões ou mais: `v1` e `v2`. Eu sei que o Spark fornece o `path()`, acredito não ser difícil.

Minha dúvida está em como realizar a estrutura das pastas com base no modelo MVC.

Obs.: Comentei o Spark por motivo de contextualização do framework que estou usando.